# How to add padding between div and button aura component

Tags: aura, html, html-area-component

How do I add padding between the div and button as shown in the screenshot below.

```html
<div class="slds-notify slds-notify_alert slds-theme_alert-texture slds-theme_warning" role="alert">
    <span class="slds-assistive-text">warning</span>
    <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-warning slds-m-right_x-small" title="Description of icon when needed">
        <lightning:icon 
            class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small" 
            aria-hidden="true" 
            iconName="utility:warning" 
            size="x-small"> 
        </lightning:icon>
    </span>
    <h2>Your profiling is expiring! </h2> 
    <br></br>
</div>
                                      
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Employee History" onclick="{!c.history}" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple options here:

1. You can add your button also to a div and maintain a space by adding `slds-p-top_medium` to button's div

   ```
        <div class="slds-notify slds-notify_alert slds-theme_alert-texture slds-theme_warning" role="alert">
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">warning</span>
        <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-warning slds-m-right_x-small" title="Description of icon when needed">
                                            <lightning:icon class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small" aria-hidden="true" iconName="utility:warning" size="x-small">
                                            </lightning:icon>
                                        </span>
        <h2>Your profiling is expiring!</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="slds-p-top_medium">
        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Employee History"/>
    </div>
   ```
2. You can achieve spacing with Margin too if you dont want to wrap your button into a div.

   ```
    <div class="slds-notify slds-notify_alert slds-theme_alert-texture slds-theme_warning" role="alert">
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">warning</span>
        <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-warning slds-m-right_x-small"
              title="Description of icon when needed">
                                                <lightning:icon class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small" aria-hidden="true"
                                                                iconName="utility:warning" size="x-small">
                                                </lightning:icon>
                                            </span>
        <h2>Your profiling is expiring!</h2>
    </div>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Employee History" class="slds-m-top_medium"/>
   ```

Comment: yep I was looking for this class `class="slds-m-top_medium"`